# bash/gnu readline multiline command: move row up/down

Tags: bash, readline, line-editor

How to move one *editing* row up (back) or down (forward) in a multi-line command in bash/readline?

Somethnig like [`gj`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#gj)/[`gk`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#gk) in [Vim](http://www.vim.org/).

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you're using Emacs keybindings in `readline` (the default), in which case you can use the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> - go to previous line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> - go to next line

If you prefer `vi` keybindings, those can be enabled by adding the following to your `~/.inputrc`: `set editing-mode vi`

Comment: Yes, emacs mode. But it's not the answer. Ctrl+P/N goes to the previous/next *command* line. I am asking how to move cursor "screen width" characters back/forward so it's looks like moving one *editing* line up/down in a (long) multi-line command.

Comment: @HansGinzel Ah, I misunderstood slightly. Unfortunately I can't see anything obvious in the readline documentation. I believe the Emacs equivalent commands would be `next-logical-line` and `previous-logical-line` but I don't think readline has anything similar.